# Media query makes tel: link not work

Tags: html, css

I am running into an issue that is bewildering me. I have  with a tel: link embedded. It works completely fine until I assign a class or ID(tried both) that uses a media query to apply {display: none;} at a certain screen width. Once the class/ID is applied the tel: link just plain doesn't work at any width.
Any help would be extremely appreciated.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 414px){ 
  #call-now{ display: none; } 
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-left" id="call-now" style="margin-left: 30%; padding-top: 12px">
  <a href="tel:1555444333" style="color: #1b95e0; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ababab; font-family:    'Rubik', sans-serif; font-size: 25px">CALL NOW</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I am explicitly saying to hide the element when the browser goes above 414px. Which it does. However when the class is applied, the tel: link is no longer clickable when the element is present. However the tel: link works fine when the ID is not applied( yes then it is always visible, I just did that as a control to make sure it wasn't something else affecting it.)

Comment: So where is the class and where is the id? Is the id on the div causing the problem? Your snippet seems to work fine.

Comment: I am using the id "call-now" which is located in the <div> the <a> is located in(also tried applying the ID to just the <a> with same result). I just was stating that I tried utilizing both a class and an ID(not at same time,  but applied the same way as to just be sure there wasn't some conflict being caused).

So while the functionality of the media query works fine, the tel: link becomes unclickable when the ID "call-now" is applied, but is clickable when i leave out the ID "call-now".

Comment: If it is not clickable, than some other element is above it! Go right click on anchor and go to inspect the element in your browser inspector.

Comment: I wish that was the case :( . I live and die by using the inspector tool, first thing I went to. The <a> shows its location right where the text is. Like I said as well, the "CALL NOW" text is clickable when I remove #call-now id. When i enter it back in, the text is unclickable. So the only conflict seems to be that the tel: is negated by the id that calls the media query.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is saying that you don't want to display the div tag if the device is any larger than 414px. I think you might want to use max-width. Also, just a suggestion: use an id or class instead of inline styling.

So you would have something like this:

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 414px){ 
   #call-now{ display: none;
              margin-left: 30%;
              padding-top: 12px; } 
    }
#call-anchor{
  color: #1b95e0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ababab;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-left" id="call-now">
  <a href="tel:1555444333" id="call-anchor">CALL NOW</a>
</div>
```